# How do I train a neural-network for a recommendation system?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recommendation-engine

I've set up an ANN with back-propagation as a book recommendation system.

I only have one hidden layer in the network, and both the input and the output layers are books, since you should be able to enter a book and receive more book recommendations.

I already have a lot of data about users and their ratings (1 to 5) for books. I'd like to get it into the neural network (set up all the weights) for this data without having to go through the back-propagation process. Do it somehow more mechanically.

Say each user has about 100 rated books in their library, how do I set the weights for them? How do the books in the user's library relate to the other books in the user's library?

Thanks.

Comment: Weight by the book ratings, that's why you have them.

Comment: This question is not about pre-training in the sense of neural nets.

Answer (score 2):

So it sounds like you don't want to use a neural network. I have found that neural networks are more difficult and take longer to train in these types of sparse feature spaces. You want to predict (I believe) books that a person might like given their ratings and the ratings of people who made similar purchases.

You should look at [collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering). I am not saying that you can't solve the problem with neural networks but I am not sure that you want would really want to.

Comment: Agreed. A neural network is not going to "have data put in it" easily - outside of using a training algorithm such as back propagation. Not say it's not possible, but that's more of a research question for someone interested in NN methinks.

A decision tree (or boosting with decision stumps) might be suitable for your application.

WEKA has these, and a nice tutorial about how to use them in WEKA can be found here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-weka1/index.html

Comment: I have tried something like this before where I ran an expensive pass over all the examples to estimate the weights and then train from there. For a NN that pass tends to be too expensive. It is cheaper to use distribution passed estimation of weights and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you probably dont't want to use a neural network.

Usually with ANNs, the initial weights are assigned random values (maybe calculated through a random number algorithm) after which they are optimised through the training iterations.

Have you looked into Fuzzy Logic theories to solve your problem? Based on my experience, it sounds like fuzzy logic may be suited to this system where the book ratings can be used as membership functions to determine which category/book to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Neural Networks are not a solution to your problem. What you need is some metric of similarity between two books. This could include some tagging mechanism, or [Dewey Classification System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification). Then, the user's recommendation should include the books that are more relevant to the ones he likes.